# ngOnChanges() don't detect route parameters

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
constructor(private http: Http,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) { 
        this.userID = this.route.snapshot.params['userID'];
    }


    ngOnChanges()
    {
        this.getUser();
    }
```

This code is from my player profile component, I get the userID from the route params and using this.getUser() to make an API call to my server.

Using ngOnInit() works, but the user is not reloading when route changes to another user while in the same component.

I changed to ngOnChanges() and now it's not being called even once. Seem like ngOnChanges works only on @Input() and I don't have one.

How I can reload my user data whenever the `userID` changes to different user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) { 
    this.userID = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getUser(params['userID']);
    })
}
```